# How to define conditional string types in Typescript like flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
type UpsertMode = | 'add' | 'update' | 'delete';

interface IUpsertMembers {
  mode: UpsertMode;
}

const MagicButton = ({ mode: UpsertMode }) => {
  return (
    <button>{mode}</button>
  );
}

const UpsertMembers = ({ mode }: IUpsertMembers) => {
  return (
    <MagicButton mode={mode} />
  );
};

export default UpsertMembers;
```

I am trying to use it inside a `.tsx file` and the type still turns out to be `any`

It gives an error saying

```
Binding element 'UpsertMode' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7031
```

Comment: ...exactly like that? This is valid Typescript code.

Comment: @kaya3 sorry for the delay in the update, but I get an error in this code while running it.

Comment: where do you use these types? add code sample and show where exactly  your code breaks

Comment: You are probably using the interface in an intersection with a type that already has a `mode` property of type `IntrinsicAttributes` and that results in this strange intersection that can't be satisfied  by any concrete value

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the initial |

```
type UpsertMode = add' | 'update' | 'delete';
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is in the binding of the `mode` variable.  You want `MagicButton` to take a single argument of type `{mode: UpsertMode}`, and then [destructure it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter)  into a function-local variable named `mode`.  To do that you have to write it like this:

```
const MagicButton = ({ mode }: { mode: UpsertMode }) => {
  return (
    <button>{ mode } < /button>
  );
}
```

This is basically the same as the annotation you have in your `UpsertMembers` function.

---

The reason why `({ mode: UpsertMode }) => ...` doesn't work is because that's just JavaScript and you have no type annotation.  It's similar to `({ mode: UpsertMode }: any) => ...`.   Here, `{mode : UpsertMode}` is doing an [object destructuring where you assign to a new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).  Meaning that the `mode` property of the input has been destructured into a function-local variable named `UpsertMode`.  Not your intent, and leads to at least two fun errors:

- since you had no type annotation, the type of `UpsertMode` in `({mode: UpsertMode})` is implicitly inferred to be `any`, which is an error with `--noImplicitAny`: `Binding element 'UpsertMode' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
- since the function has no local variable named `mode`, your use of `mode` in the function is an error: `Cannot find name 'mode'.`

---

If you think that you shouldn't have to write `mode` twice just to get both a destructuring assignment binding and a type annotation, you're not alone.  There's an open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526), in which it's suggested to allow something like `({mode :: UpsertMode}) => ...` to indicate that `UpsertMode` is a type and not a variable name.  If you want to increase the chance of this happening, you might want to head over to that issue and give it a .

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgFUwBnJWAWQgBN6BeOAD4EUXLvkEEArmC4oYScUPw8ANknllKwAHbyomdPQCSTVhyQgARm2ZwA3uThwQ3JAC5GLNjE48KAX0o0CG1meHYUAHNgNAAhSRgYELh+AAo7Z1c4fw8Mlx4PU29fen8AShSAPntHOCIYSShtOFTapwAeSwSk7Uq7fKR-doB6LsSQytqygKCQsM8zHwtrKFs0vKycuBMvcysbCt5qhyd6xubWpw6I6Lju5IHeftd-OGHJp2nyfwpyJAAPSCwOA8AySFTwIp7FbMChAA)